# What is the probability that a number greater than 3 is picked in the second step?

Tags: probability

Question:

First one number is chosen uniformly at random from {1,2,3,4,5} and is removed from the set; then a second number is chosen uniformly at random from the remaining numbers. What is the probability that a number greater than 3 is picked in the second step?

My attempt:

STEP 1: FIND THE SAMPLE SPACE

The first and second number removed from {1,2,3,4,5}

Sample space S =
{(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5),

(2,1), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5),

(3,1), (3,2), (3,4), (3,5),

(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,5),

(5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4)}

STEP 2: DEFINE EVENT OF INTEREST

Event of interest is a number greater than 3 is picked in the second step

E = {(1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5) , (3,4), (3,5), (4,5), (5,4)}

STEP 3: DETERMINE OUTCOME PROBABILITIES:

Pr[(1,4)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(1,5)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(2,4)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(2,5)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(3,4)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(3,5)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(4,5)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

Pr[(5,4)] = 1/5 x 1/4 = 1/20

STEP 4: COMPUTE EVENT PROBABILITIES

Pr[a number greater than 3 is picked in the second step] = Pr[(1,4)] + Pr[(1,5)] + Pr[(2,4)] + Pr[(2,5)] + Pr[(3,4)] + Pr[(3,5)] + Pr[(4,5)] + Pr[(5,4)]

= 1/20 + 2/10 + 2/10 + 1/20 + 1/20 + 1/20 + 1/20 + + 1/20

= 8/20

= 2/5 = 0.4

Comment: You may omit the steps 3 and 4, and simply divide the cardinality of the second set by that of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is right. Another way is by using conditioning.

---

There are five cases at the first step. You need to condition on each of these five to get the probability of picking up a number greater than 3 in second step.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[\text{Pick Number $> 3$ in second step}] &= \mathbb P[\text{First number is $1,2,3$}]\cdot\\&\quad\qquad \mathbb P[\text{Second number $>3$}|\text{First number is $1,2,3$}]+\\&\qquad\mathbb P[\text{First number is $4,5$}]\cdot \\&\quad\qquad\mathbb P[\text{Second number $>3$}|\text{First number is $4,5$}]\\
&= \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
&= \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\\
&= \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

The chances of the second number being greater than $(3)$ are the same as the chances of the first number being greater than $(3)$.

To prove this:

Write each of the numbers $(1)$ through $(5)$, each on a separate sheet of paper.  Then, turn each of the sheets rightside down, so that the numbers written on the sheets are not visible.

Then, scramble the sheets.

Then, choose one of the sheets at random, and label this sheet $(A)$.

Then, choose a second sheet at random, from the remaining sheets, and label this sheet $(B)$.

The sheet labeled $(A)$ will represent the first number drawn.

The sheet labeled $(B)$ will represent the second number drawn.

Given the method used to format and then select the sheets, the chances that sheet $(A)$ has a $(4)$ or a $(5)$ must be equivalent to the chances that sheet $(B)$ has a $(4)$ or a $(5)$.